# Running Total With Subtraction SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample dataset

| ID | DATE | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 116210 | 4/16/2021 | 570,788 |
| 116210 | 4/17/2021 | 57,152 |
| 116210 | 4/18/2021 | 57,152,106 |
| 116210 | 4/19/2021 | 5,549,211 |
| 116210 | 4/20/2021 | 5,748,370 |
| 116210 | 4/21/2021 | 5,425,046 |

What i want to do is to monitor daily movement of the balances as follows

| ID | DATE | BALANCE | MOVEMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 116210 | 4/16/2021 | 570,788 | 0 |
| 116210 | 4/17/2021 | 57,152 | (513,636) |
| 116210 | 4/18/2021 | 57,152,106 | 57,094,954 |
| 116210 | 4/19/2021 | 5,549,211 | (51,602,895) |
| 116210 | 4/20/2021 | 5,748,370 | 199,159 |
| 116210 | 4/21/2021 | 5,425,046 | (323,324) |

I have written the following script

```
   SELECT id, 
      [date],
      balance,
    balance-SUM([balance]) OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [id],[date])
    AS movement
    FROM [corporate].[dbo].[balances_apr]
```

However, it is adding the balances instead of subtracting

Comment: The amounts in the movement column do not seem to add up.

Comment: Its today's balance minus previous day's balance. Will update to use an example with positive balances

Comment: I'm not going to answer your question due to lack of copy-friendly data (sql fiddle, scripts etc.) but I'd hazard a guess you need to use LAG over() on the balance to get the difference between the current row and the previous.

Comment: @LoztInSpace, used LAG as follows  ```balance - ( LAG( balance) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id,[date]))

Answer (score 4):

You can use LAG function and subtract from Balance, as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @test table(ID  int, vDATE date,    BALANCE int)

insert into @test values
(116210 ,'4/16/2021',   570788      )
,(116210    ,'4/17/2021',   57152       )
,(116210    ,'4/18/2021',   57152106    )
,(116210    ,'4/19/2021',   5549211     )
,(116210    ,'4/20/2021',   5748370     )
,(116210    ,'4/21/2021',   5425046     );

SELECT ID, VdATE, Balance, iif(balance = movement, 0, movement) as movement FROM
(
SELECT ID,VDate, Balance, balance - LAG(Balance,1,0) over (partition by id order by vDate) as movement FROM @test
) AS T
```

| ID | VdATE | Balance | movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 116210 | 2021-04-16 | 570788 | 0 |
| 116210 | 2021-04-17 | 57152 | -513636 |
| 116210 | 2021-04-18 | 57152106 | 57094954 |
| 116210 | 2021-04-19 | 5549211 | -51602895 |
| 116210 | 2021-04-20 | 5748370 | 199159 |
| 116210 | 2021-04-21 | 5425046 | -323324 |

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, DT DATE, Balance INT);

INSERT @t values
(116210 ,'4/16/2021','570788'),
(116210 ,'4/17/2021','57152'),
(116210 ,'4/18/2021','57152106'),
(116210 ,'4/19/2021','5549211'),
(116210 ,'4/20/2021','5748370'),
(116210 ,'4/21/2021','5425046')

SELECT t.ID, t.DT, t.Balance,
       Movement = t.Balance - LAG(t.Balance,1,t.Balance) OVER (ORDER BY t.DT)
FROM @t AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID          DT         Balance     Movement
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
116210      2021-04-16 570788      0
116210      2021-04-17 57152       -513636
116210      2021-04-18 57152106    57094954
116210      2021-04-19 5549211     -51602895
116210      2021-04-20 5748370     199159
116210      2021-04-21 5425046     -323324
```